# Something similar to owasp for wifi/networks/desktop/servers/...?

Tags: web-application, penetration-test

Is there a site or project similar to owasp.org for other systems or devices which a commonly subject to penetration testing?

Which ones?

Comment: I guess you could look at the NVD: https://nvd.nist.gov/

Comment: OWASP covers a very broad spectrum for web applications. What is it about OWASP that you want for other systems or devices?

Comment: @schroeder the comprehensive and systematic testing checklist https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Testing_Guide_v4_Table_of_Contents is what interests me most.

Answer (score 1):

There are many sites dedicated to these topics. There's the National Vulnerability Database, which has both CVEs, known vulnerabilities, and CCEs, configuration issues. https://nvd.nist.gov/

There's the NIAP program which covers a wide variety of products. https://www.niap-ccevs.org/Product/

You can look at the Center for Internet Security benchmarks, which also covers a wide variety: https://benchmarks.cisecurity.org/